# How to calculate correct value of capacitor C2?

Tags: measurement, capacity

I have the following connection, what should be the correct capacity of C2, for the case when the device is turned on, so it will load untill my MC will be not ready? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Huh?  *Load until my MC will not be ready* is gibberish.  We use English here.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation, I meant the duration of the transient process between the 0V level on the EVB and 3.3V level, so I have measured this time with oscilloscope, and have found the correct capacity

Comment: @AndreyMazur If you have found the correct capacity, then what is the question?

Comment: @AndreyMazur there is insufficient information to debug your problem, I would suspect a few paragraphs would adaquatley explain the problem. This question will be closed, if you want to you can edit it and reopen it. Please clearly state the problem, then ask a good question(s) http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have tried values, found one which works, and are done?

The voltage between R1 and C2 (EN pin) follows the law of the [RC time constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant). So initally C2 is discharged and EN = 0v. \$\tau\$ = 200k*100p = 20µS. So 20µS after power is applied, V_EN will be ≈ 63.2 percent of Vcc or 2.09v. (Loading from VREF2, EN, and T1 may alter this.)